# How to Select Auto-Generate Classes in Javascript puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, css-selectors, puppeteer

I'm trying to select the "Use phone / email / username" using puppeteer on the http://tiktok.com/ (you can check out the HTML there) (As referenced below)
[image: Example of Trying to select]

At first I thought I could just do

```
await page.$eval( '.channel-name-2qzLW', form => form.click() );
```

But the issue is that puppeteer cant find an element with that class because I think the puppeteer browser has a different one as the channel name is automatically generator. As a result I tried finding out how to select an element with the text of Use phone / email / username as that's specific but I ran into issues outlined below.

I tried selecting the divs that contain the text element:

```
await page.$eval( 'div["Use phone / email / username"]', form => form.click() );
```

But I received an error message

```
Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'div["Use phone or email"]' is not a valid selector.
```

I've tried looking at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and https://www.checklyhq.com/learn/headless/basics-selectors/ for an idea of how to get the element but I;m still not sure.

(Current code):

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  // Goes to tiktok website
  await page.goto('https://tiktok.com');
  // Clicks on Upload text
  await page.$eval( '.upload-text', form => form.click() );
  // issue occurs here as it can't find this element
  await page.$eval( '.channel-name-2qzLW', form => form.click() );
  // screenshots the webpage so I can see what it sees
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'browserView.png' });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the class is an attribute, you can use the wildcard selector.

```
div[class*="channel-name-"]
```

This selector will target all div elements with classes that partially match "channel-name-".

**However**, I want to point out that relying on a wildcard selector  is not the optimal solution, because if not defined correctly it might return incorrect results. Plus, even though today's machines are fast and strong enough for this tiny extra work, it's still not a very efficient way for a solution, especially with large and complex pages.

So you can use it, but pay more attention.